# Retagging [google] questions

Tags: discussion, retag-request

[Some of the questions](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/google-chrome+google) tagged with [google](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/google) actually relate only to Google Chrome and not to Google products / Google company in general, for example:

- [How does Google Chrome installer work?](https://superuser.com/questions/238357/how-does-google-chrome-installer-work)
- [Google Chrome issues](https://superuser.com/questions/472785/google-chrome-issues)
- [How to get google chrome to stop changing the address I enter?](https://superuser.com/questions/479444/how-to-get-google-chrome-to-stop-changing-the-address-i-enter)

The [google](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/google) tag wiki should be edited too:

> Tag is intend to mark questions related to the products of Google your
>   using on your computer.
>
> - Google website and search engine
> - Wikipedia article on Google Inc.

Since there's already a [google-search](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/google-search) tag. I think the [google](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/google) tag should be like the [mozilla](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/mozilla) tag - it should relate either to the company itself or to its products in general. Google.com questions should be tagged only with [google-search](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/google-search). So there's no way there are 424 question about Google Inc. / Google products in general. Most of them are about the Google search engine or about Google Chrome.
[Some questions](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/google+search) are tagged with [google](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/google)[search](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/search) instead of [google-search](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/google-search), too.

Comment: Also, generally questions on Google Search (or any other web-based Google product) is off-topic on [su] and should be on [webapps.se].